# CSS float and text align works only as inline

Tags: html, css, razor, css-float, inline-styles

I have an app done with ASP .net core 2.1. 
I modified it is scuffolded crud details page.
However I am stuck at dl,dt and dd elements.

The text in dt elements, which holds name of the fields are adjacent to the right side. and no matter what i did I couldn`t change it except I added and inline style code.
I put the code below at the style section of the file :

```
<style>
    dd {
        min-width: 120px;
        background: #dd0
    }

    dt {
        float: left;
        background: #cc0;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
```

This code makes no changes in terms of float and text align, yet it does take effect for background as shown in picture below.
[image: it works for first two lines]

But When I put those display settings inline like below, it works just fine for those lines like in picture above.

```
<dt style="text-align: left; max-width: 70px;">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PatientName)
                    </dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PatientName)
                    </dd>
                    <dt style="text-align: left;min-width: 70px;">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PatientAddress)
                    </dt>
```

That made me think maybe it is a hierarchy of setting but I tried even the bootstrap and no luck again.

And I don`t want to put the settings inline as it is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

[CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) determines the order in which CSS rules get applied, so try adding selectors of increasing specificity until you get the desired result.

From the linked website:

> The following list of selector types increases by specificity:
>
> 1. Type selectors (e.g., `h1`) and pseudo-elements (e.g., `::before`).
> 2. Class selectors (e.g., `.example`), attributes selectors (e.g., `[type="radio"]`) and pseudo-classes (e.g., `:hover`).
> 3. ID selectors (e.g., `#example`).
>
> Other rules:
>
> - Universal selector (`*`), combinators (`+`, `>`, `~`, `' '`, `||`) and negation pseudo-class (`:not()`) have no effect on specificity.
>     (The selectors declared inside `:not()` do, however.)
> - Inline styles added to an element (e.g., `style="font-weight: bold;"`) always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets, and thus
>     can be thought of as having the highest specificity.
> - The `!important` rule: When an `!important` rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declarations.

Here are examples of selectors based on the types listed above that you should try:

```
/* Type selectors (your current method): */

dd
dt

/* Class selectors (either directly on elements, or on parent <table class="my-table"> */

dd.my-class
dt.my-class
/* or */
table.my-table dd
table.my-table dt

/* ID selectors (either directly on elements, or on parent <table id="my-table"> */

dd.my-dd
dt.my-dt
/* or */
table#my-table dd
table#my-table dt
```

Like you mentioned, if all else fails you can resort to using **bad practice** methods that completely override all CSS selectors: inline styles or the `!important` rule:

```
<style>
    dd {
        min-width: 120px !important;
        background: #dd0 !important;
    }

    dt {
        float: left;
        background: #cc0 !important;
        text-align: left !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. so, I understand that this "!important" makes that part override everything. is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, and that's why it's considered bad practice. I guess it would be better to add `id` attributes to the `<dd>` and `<dt>` elements for ultimate specificity, or even to the `<table>` element. I'll update my answer accordingly.